# Overpass API & reducing the output size

Tags: overpass-api

I'm pretty new to using the Overpass API but we are looking to calculate areas & ways (of certain types) which either contain a particular coordinate or are close to a specified coordinate.

So far we have this, which 'seems' to work:

```
[out:json];
(
way(around:25, 28.416830, -81.581877)(if: (is_tag("building")) || (is_tag("leisure") && t["leisure"] == "park") || (is_tag("tourism")) || (is_tag("place")));

  is_in(28.416830, -81.581877)->.a; 
area.a(if: (is_tag("building")) || (is_tag("leisure") && t["leisure"] == "park") || (is_tag("tourism")) ||
 (is_tag("place")))->.building;
way(pivot.building);  
);

out geom;
```

But we intend to be making our requests from mobile devices so want to try and remove as much from the resultant json as possible e.g. don't include non english name tags.  Similarly we aren't interested in the 'nodes' but the geometry is required.

Is this possible or would we need to do some of our own server based work to remove those elements we don't require?